# Alerting items in two minipages of a frame in beamer

Tags: highlighting

I divided a frame into 2 parts side by side by minipage. In the first part I have 6 items and 7 items (images) in the second part (please have a look at the following).

```
\begin{frame}

 \frametitle{Preliminaries} 

 \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blue,bg=}

\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=magenta,bg=}

\usebeamercolor{normal text}

 \noindent

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.58\linewidth}

\begin{enumerate}

  \item \alert<+>{some text here}

  \item \alert<+>{some text here}

  \item\alert<+>{some text here}

  \item\alert<+>{some text here}

  \item \alert<+>{some text here}

  \item \alert<+>{some text here}

 \end{enumerate}

\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}

\vspace*{0.25in}

\begin{center}

   \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.5]{image1}

   \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.5]{image2}

   \includegraphics<3>[scale=0.5]{image3}

   \includegraphics<4>[scale=0.5]{image4}

   \vspace*{-0.3in}

   \includegraphics<5>[scale=0.35]{image5}

   \includegraphics<6>[scale=0.35]{image6}

   \includegraphics<7>[scale=0.35]{image7}

 \end{center}

\end{minipage}

\end{frame}
```

Now the question is, how to keep (highlight) the color for the first item in the first part while the first two images in the second part are being displayed? and when I display the 3rd image, the second item in the first part should be highlighted, but not the 1st item and so on. How do I do this?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\alert<1-2>`, `\alert<3>`, `\alert<4>` etc instead of `\alert<+>`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % never seen anyone using these
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Preliminaries} 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blue,bg=}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=magenta,bg=}
\usebeamercolor{normal text}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}[t]{0.58\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \alert<1-2>{some text here}
  \item \alert<3>{some text here}
  \item \alert<4>{some text here}
  \item \alert<5>{some text here}
  \item \alert<6>{some text here}
  \item \alert<7>{some text here}
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}

  \begin{column}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
  \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.2]{example-image}
  \includegraphics<2>[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
  \includegraphics<3>[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
  \includegraphics<4>[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}
  \includegraphics<5>[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
  \includegraphics<6>[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
  \includegraphics<7>[scale=0.2]{example-image-c}
  \end{center}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]